# How to create a parent category dropdown in admin form in magento2.2

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, ui-form, php-7.2

I want to create a drop-down field in admin **UI-component** form in magento2.(for getting parent category/post) How to do that

[image]

How to do that

Thanks